# Pause until date in SharePoint Workflow

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a workflow that runs when an item is added and updated. It calls a webservice i'm running on azure. It mails a user about the event is added or updated.

But i work with pause until date. But when an item is added everything is working fine.

The problem starts when i'm updating the event to a new date then a second workflow is starting. But when a date is changed it should kill the first workflow or update it with the new date. So i don't have to run 2 workflows.

Is something possible?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please specify which version of SharePoint workflow you are using?
If its 2013 then we can use Parallel blocks and set them up in a way such that if one completes rest are cancelled. Please read [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/07/05/run-only-one-not-all-of-parallel-actions-with-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/). 
Parallel block 1:

1. Pause until "Event Date" (Item Added)
2. set condition to true so that second parallel block can end.

Parallel Block 2:

1. Add a loop
2. Inside the loop wait for field change (Event Date)
3. set condition to true so that first parallel block can end.
4. if there's a change, again pause or do whatever you need to do
5. loop restarts

Parallel block 2 take care of the situation where event date is updated. Also loop will only start once and you could add a condition in the workflow to end it accordingly so that its not always running.